# Align two divs side by side?

Tags: html, css

How to align two div elements side by side while specifying the width of only the right div? I want the right div to be of fixed width and the left div to take the remaining space.

```
<div style="width:100%;"><div class="left">left div</div>
<div class="right">right div</div></div>
.left{
float:left;
background:green;
width:100%;
}
.right{    
background:red;
width:200px;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`float:right;` your "right" div, and put it first:

```html
<div style="height:100px; width:100px; background-color:red; float:right;"></div>
<div style="height:100px; background-color:blue;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative margins to negate the width of the fixed with element, then float the fixed width element to the right.

```css
.left{
    float: left;
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -200px;
}
.right{    
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%;">
    <div class="left">left div</div>
    <div class="right">right div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS `calc` to do this with pretty good browser support(http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc):

```css
.left{
    float:left;
    background:green;
  
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
.right{    
    background:red;
    width:200px;
  
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%;"><div class="left">left div</div>
<div class="right">right div</div></div>
```

Comment: It's neat that you can do this, but unnecessary and will kill performance.

Comment: The more options the better in my opinion. I do like your solution though +1.

Answer (score 0):

To align to Divs next to eachother you give them both `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` or `float: left` but you cannot align anything next to a div with `width: 100%`. Because that basically means you want that Div to take up the entire row. so nothing can fix next to it. By changing the width to be something other than 100% and giving both divs `float: left` you will accomplish what you want like this http://jsfiddle.net/6707pn01/